# Entering elements into an array and checking to see if the element already exists

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm working on a problem and i've tried it every way I can think of with a for loop but i can't figure out how to make it work as I only started on c# and programming as a whole a few weeks ago.

Write an app that inputs five numbers. As each number is read search the array if the number doesn’t exist in the array output the word “new” and insert the number into the array. If the number does exist in the array output “exists”. Once all five numbers have been entered output the content of the array.

This is what I have so far. Thanks for any help

```
using System;

public class Program
{
   // Main method begins execution of C# application
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      int[] array = new int[5];

      for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
         array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

         for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
         {

            if (array[i] != array[a])
            {
               array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
               Console.WriteLine("new\n");
            }

         }

         array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
         Console.WriteLine("exists\n");
      }

      Console.WriteLine(array);
      Console.ReadKey();
   }
} // end class
```

Comment: Homework question? Looks to me as if the logic of your code isn't quite right. You are looping 5 times asking for a number, then looping again 5 times within that.  Have another look at how you've structured what you're doing and follow it in the debugger

Comment: That question is about a string array and doesn't show how to check each element as it is entered to see if it is new or exists

Comment: @jigmurphy minor corrections will solve this.  array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  why are you reading here ? and also change logic if it exists print exist and then loop is over and it is not there set as new. may be you can add a flag

Comment: I'm having trouble comparing the new element to the elements in the array. I've removed the second loop as it is unnecessary. Will something like this work?    
     if (array[i] != array[a])

Comment: @jigmurphy I don't understand what problem you are facing. In the code you provided you are adding the element to the array before checking if it already exists.

Comment: The questions is beyond close enough to a duplicate. The answer to it can be trivially adapted to answer this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.Any()` in `System.Linq`. Also, you don't need to continuously grab user input in your loop:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
  // Main method begins execution of C# application
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    int[] array = new int[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
      // Get user input and convert to integer:
      int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

      // Check if given input is already in the array: 
      if (! array.Any(number => number == input))
      {
          array[i] = input;
          Console.WriteLine("new\n");
      }
      else 
      {
          Console.WriteLine("exists\n");
      }
    }

    // Print the contents of array separated by ','
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", array));
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

Edit: Another variant if you want the user to fill the array completely:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    // Btw, if this is not an array of nullables,
    // we will not be able to insert a zero later, as
    // we will treat them as duplicates.
    int?[] array = new int?[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");

      int input = 0;
      bool duplicateAttempt = false;
      do {
        // Get and convert the input.
        input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        // See if this number is already in.
        duplicateAttempt = array.Contains(input);
        // Report if we attempt to insert a duplicate.
        if (duplicateAttempt) Console.WriteLine("exists");
      } 
      while (duplicateAttempt); // Keep asking while we don't get a unique number.

      array[i] = input; // Store the number
      Console.WriteLine("new");
    }

    // Print the contents of array separated by ','
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", array));
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

Comment: But this will only add one item to the array if they enter the same number 5 times. OP needs to add 5 items...

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what i was looking for. I'll spend the next while figuring out how each part works but cheers for this!

Comment: @RufusL OP doesn't state this anywhere, but I added an edit that does it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all try thinking about a solution before you actually start writing some code, couple of hints

1. You expect some user input, we will use a variable to save the user input
2. You need to validate that the values does not exist in you array or structure, this can be done using the `Contains` method.
3. If it exists we continue to the next user input and print the required message.
4. If the value does not exists we add the value and print the new message

We will do this until the `Count` of the structure is equal to 5.

for reference use this [While loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while), [Hashset.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [Hashset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

try this:

```
var numbers = new HashSet<int>();   
    while(numbers.Count < 5)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:"); //1.
         var number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (numbers.Contains(number)) // 2.
        {
             Console.WriteLine("exists\n"); //3.
             continue;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("new\n"); //4.
        numbers.Add(number);
    }

    foreach (var n in numbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues with your code. You should only increment the array index if successful - otherwise the missing values will be zero. It's also a good idea to validate the input in case the user entered an invalid value. You can use linq to check if the value already exists in the array:

Here's an example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array = new int[5];
        var index = 0; 
        while (index < array.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            var value = 0;
            if (!int.TryParse(input, out value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error - value entered was not a number");
            }
            else
            {
                var match = array.Where(a => a == value);
                if (match.Any())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("exists\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    array[index] = value;
                    Console.WriteLine("new\n");
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: looks like a home work question..couple of hints might help him get started rather than giving solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a homework question, so I think it's more helpful to explain what you've done wrong and tell you what you should do...

It won't help you learn to copy and paste other people's answers.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
   // Main method begins execution of C# application
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      int[] array = new int[5];

      for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
// you are putting the value into your array here.  so it will always 'exist' below
         array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());  

// you need to do this check before you insert the number into the array
// put the ReadLine into a variable, not directly into the array.  
// then check if it's in the array already 
         for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
         {

            if (array[i] != array[a])
            {
// here you are trying to read another value from the user.  
// Console.ReadLine() will always wait for user input
// use the variable from above.  but only after you have looped through all the items.
// and verified that it is not present
               array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
               Console.WriteLine("new\n");
            }

         }
// this is the third time you have assigned the number to the array
// and the third time you've asked for user input per loop
         array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
         Console.WriteLine("exists\n");
      }

      Console.WriteLine(array);
      Console.ReadKey();
   }
} // end class
```

To summarize:

you need a for loop that runs 5 times.

The for loop will do the following:

- assign the user input to a variable
- loop through your array (second loop) and see if it contains this variable
- if the number is found, set a boolean to true. (found)
- if after the loop is over, found = false, then print false
- also add the number to the array (at the index of the outer loop is fine)